# Ubuntu Touch - Notification bar not displaying new Telegram user picture

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification, telegram

One of my Telegram contacts has changed their user picture recently and the new image is not being displayed in the notifications. The notification bar is displaying the old user image however, when Telegram is opened the new user image is displayed correctly. How do I refresh the Telegram user image in the notifications bar, so that it fetches the new image?

Comment: I have turned of the Telegram notifications in Settings and then on again (after receiving a few messages) and this did not help.

Comment: Not had any friends that have recently changed their profile picture. But would be a good idea to log this in launchpad.

Comment: I have raised this in launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/contacts/+bug/1664092